Cmd command execution with Popen Python
I want to execute command below using Popen:
call "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsprepost48/lsdynamsvar.bat"   && "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsdyna_sp.exe" i=C:/Users/User/Desktop/ls-dyna_python/Project_1/qd_env/1/projects/1_1_1/1_1_1.k ncpu=1 memory=20m

Also how to run it in another folder? For example in "Desktop/Work/"
I don't really get how to use Popen in this way, what should I list?
subprocess.Popen [*whole command*]?
subprocess.Popen ['call', '*rest*']?
It's doesn't work for me, I don't understand what are arguments here
It works with os.system('cmd /k "*command*").
I don't really care about checking output.
I want to use Popen to use process.wait() next.

You need shell=True in order for call to behave as desired, because it's amending the environment variables active within a shell; this means, further, that you want to pass a single string for that shell to parse, not a list of individual arguments. Beyond that, though, we'd need to see what you tried and how it failed to speak further.

(Also, one question to a question, please; "How to run it in another folder?" is already asked and answered elsewhere on this site: How can I specify the working directory for a subprocess?)

...mind, I don't know why process.wait() is important or useful to you -- os.system() blocks just as much subprocess.Popen().wait() does. In almost every circumstance I recommend using subprocess.Popen instead of os.system, but you may well be in a case where it doesn't matter much.

Popen syntax is explained better in here.Check this

Thank you for your answers! I will try options from last comm.
I tried this:


process = subprocess.Popen(['call "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsprepost48/lsdynamsvar.bat"   && "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsdyna_sp.exe" i=C:/Users/User/Desktop/ls-dyna_python/Project_1/qd_env/1/projects/1_1_1/1_1_1.k ncpu=1 memory=20m'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


Same command but  process = subprocess.Popen(['call', rest part of the command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


Same command but listing every word


Without shell=True



if you want to use call and && then you have to run with shell=True because these are commands in shell. And when you use shell=True then you should use Popen("all command in one string") without [ ]

If you're running it from cmd.exe the call command is completely unnnecessary and should not be used. The call command is for running one batch file from another batch file, and you aren't doing that. You should pre-configure the working directory, "Desktop/Work", (likely after having used python to grab the value of the environment variable USERPROFILE), in python before running the commands you need. You may also benefit from creating a variable in python to shorten the repeated use of the path E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\.

The Windows command CALL is an internal command of the Windows Command Processor cmd.exe. Its help can be read by opening a command prompt window and running call /?. The command CALL is for calling one batch program from another, i.e. for calling a batch file from within a batch file or a subroutine within same batch file. This is not the case here. CALL is not needed at all.

There is no need to run cmd.exe for interpreting E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\lsprepost48\lsdynamsvar.bat and then let cmd.exe call the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess with a filled out STARTUPINFO structure for running E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\lsdyna_sp.exe with the specified arguments.

Please read the two linked Microsoft documentation pages for function CreateProcess and structure STARTUPINFO. Then read also Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces for learning that the directory separator on Windows is \ and not / as on Linux/Mac. Finally read the Python documentation pages about the subprocess module and about os.environ.

You should have the necessary knowledge for this task after reading also the Python documentation String and Bytes literals. Look on E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\lsprepost48\lsdynamsvar.bat and see which environment variables are defined new or are modified by this batch file. You can also open a command prompt window, run first set >"%USERPROFILE%\Environment_Before.txt", then run "E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\lsprepost48\lsdynamsvar.bat" and run next set >"%USERPROFILE%\Environment_After.txt"

Compare the two files %USERPROFILE%\Environment_Before.txt and %USERPROFILE%\Environment_After.txt. You can easily see which environment variables must be modified or defined for E:\Ansys\ANSYS Inc\v222\ansys\bin\winx64\lsdyna_sp.exe. The text files comparison can be done with fc "%USERPROFILE%\Environment_Before.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Environment_After.txt" on not having a better comparison tool. Now you have two options: 1. Modify with os.environ the environment variables in memory of python.exe interpreting your Python script file before using subprocess.Popen as needed.

2. Make a copy of the array of environment variables of python.exe interpreting your Python script file and modify this copy by changing and adding environment variables in this copy. Then pass this modified environment variables array to suprocess.Popen which passes it further to CreateProcess. There must be finally executed with subprocess.Popen just "E:\\Ansys\\ANSYS Inc\\v222\\ansys\\bin\\winx64\\lsdyna_sp.exe" with the arguments "i=C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ls-dyna_python\\Project_1\\qd_env\\1\\projects\\1_1_1\\1_1_1.k", "ncpu=1" and "memory=20m".

The function parameter cwd="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Work" should be also used to define the current working directory for the executable started via suprocess.Popen by CreateProcess. That's it. A batch file processed by cmd.exe for setting up the environment variables as needed by lsdyna_sp.exe is not needed at all which means the execution of cmd.exe is not needed at all. That makes the Python coding task much easier as it is not necessary to support the syntax of two interpreters – python.exe and cmd.exe – because of one interpreter – python.exe – is enough for this task.

The comments gave the answer I needed, the following helped:
process = subprocess.Popen('call "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsprepost48/lsdynamsvar.bat"   && "E:/Ansys/ANSYS Inc/v222/ansys/bin/winx64/lsdyna_sp.exe" i=C:/Users/User/Desktop/ls-dyna_python/Project_1/qd_env/1/projects/1_1_1/1_1_1.k ncpu=1 memory=20m',shell=True,cwd="C:/Users/User/Desktop/ls-dyna_python/Project_1/qd_env/1/projects/1_1_1")

So here Popen without [], command in one string, also shell=True was used.
For execution in exact folder paramater cwd="path" was used.
Thanks all for help.
